# Nuxt.js: Contact form submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am using server middleware to handle the POST from a contact form.

The problem is, it doesn't seem like the middleware file I created runs. I added breakpoints using VS Code, and they don't fire in the `contact.js`, but they do fire in the `contact.vue` (in VS Code I made sure to add the breakpoints in the appropriate client/server side environments). Even the console log info I have in the `contact.js` doesn't appear. It is like the file is being missed.

What happens is the POST call is made and stays open, with no response. The POST'd attributes and values are all there.

I suspect that the `createTransport({sendmail: true})` to fail as I don't have sendmail on my development system, but no error is thrown.

Can you see if there is anything I am missing? All I want to do is simply send an email when the form is submitted, but it seems so difficult!

I was guided by https://blog.lichter.io/posts/emails-through-nuxtjs/

All packages are installed.

This is how I have it set up...

`nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
.
.
.
  serverMiddleware: [
    '~/api/contact'
  ],
.
.
.
}
```

`pages/contact.vue`

```js
<template>
.
.
.
            <form class="form-email row mx-0"
              data-success="Thanks for your enquiry, we'll be in touch shortly."
              data-error="Please fill in all fields correctly."
              @submit.prevent="submitForm">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-12 text-xl"> <label>Your Name:</label> <input v-model="name" type="text" name="name"
                  class="validate-required"> </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-12 text-xl"> <label>Email Address:</label> <input v-model="email" type="email" name="email"
                  class="validate-required validate-email"> </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-12 text-xl"> <label>Message:</label> <textarea v-model="message" rows="4" name="message"
                  class="validate-required"></textarea> </div>
              <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-6"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary type--uppercase">Submit</button> </div>
            </form>
.
.
.
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        message: ''
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      mr.documentReady($);
      mr.windowLoad($);
    },

    methods: {
      async submitForm () {
        try {
          await this.$axios.$post('', {
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            msg: this.message
          });
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2500));
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

`api/contact.js`

```js
const express = require('express')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const validator = require('validator')
const xssFilters = require('xss-filters')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(405).json({ error: 'sorry!' })
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  const attributes = ['name', 'email', 'message'] // Our three form fields, all required

  // Map each attribute name to the validated and sanitized equivalent (false if validation failed)
  const sanitizedAttributes = attributes.map(n => validateAndSanitize(n, req.body[n]))

  // True if some of the attributes new values are false -> validation failed
  const someInvalid = sanitizedAttributes.some(r => !r)

  if (someInvalid) {
    // Throw a 422 with a neat error message if validation failed
    return res.status(422).json({ 'error': 'Ugh.. That looks unprocessable!' })
  }

  sendMail(...sanitizedAttributes)
  res.status(200).json({ 'message': 'OH YEAH' })
})

module.exports = {
  path: '/api/contact',
  handler: app
}

const validateAndSanitize = (key, value) => {
  const rejectFunctions = {
    name: v => v.length < 4,
    email: v => !validator.isEmail(v),
    message: v => v.length < 25
  }

  // If object has key and function returns false, return sanitized input. Else, return false
  return rejectFunctions.hasOwnProperty(key) && !rejectFunctions[key](value) && xssFilters.inHTMLData(value)
}

const sendMail = (name, email, message) => {
  console.info('Info: '
        +'\n Contact page submission.'
        +'\n Date: '+ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() +' '+ new Date().toLocaleDateString()
        +'\n Name: '+ name
        +'\n Email: '+ email
        +'\n Message: '
        +'\n'
        +'\n'+ message
        +'\n'
        +'\n End of submission.'
        +'\n');
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    sendmail: true,
    newline: 'unix',
    path: '/usr/sbin/sendmail'
  })
  transporter.sendMail({
    from: email,
    to: 'mail@foobar.com',
    subject: 'Foo Bar: Contact Form',
    text: message
  }, (err, info) => {
    console.log(info.envelope);
    console.log(info.messageId);
  })
}
```

Comment: I even tried changing it to `await this.$axios.$post('/', {` with the forward slash

Comment: Probably worth switching to an SMTP-basede method if you don't have sendmail installed. Feel free to take inspirations from https://github.com/Developmint/developmint.de/blob/master/functions/contact.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@manniL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975480/mannil) kindly pointed out to me on a call that in my `nuxt.config.js` I had set up the environment to load on 0.0.0.0 so that I could access it from a different machine.

```js
export default {
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
  },
  ...
}
```

I needed to also setup the axios config with the same IP address, which is why it could not find the `api/contact.js`.

I have since learnt that the default scaffold for Nuxt2, when including axios, is it adds this to the `nuxt.config.js` to cover changes in IP:

```js
export default {
  ...
  axios: {
    baseURL: '/'
  },
  ...
}
```

---

Apologies, I should have posted my full `nuxt.config.js` in the question as it was different from a default setup.

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a [Nuxt.js module](https://github.com/dword-design/nuxt-mail) that allows to send emails via a route and an injected variable. You can use it like this:

```sh
$ npm install nuxt-mail @nuxtjs/axios
```

In your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
export default {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    ['nuxt-mail', {
      smtp: {
        host: "smtp.example.com",
        port: 587,
      },
    }],
  ],
}
```

Use it in your component:

```js
this.$mail.send({
  from: 'John Doe',
  subject: 'Incredible',
  text: 'This is an incredible test message',
  to: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
})
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28508975)

Comment: @desertnaut Like this?

Comment: Yes, just in time - post had already 4 votes recommending deletion. Keep in mind for the next time that link-only answers are eligible for deletion.

Comment: @desertnaut Oh ok thanks for the hint and for keeping the post! I didn't get an email notification on the first comment which is why I was late.

Comment: I am configuring a Sendinblue SMTP but i get a 405 response back. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Yours doesn't work because you are not calling the correct path, in your `serverMiddleware` you said that `/api/contact` points to the `contact.js` file.

This means that `/api/contact` equals at the routes of that `contact.js`, thus, you should call:

```js
this.$axios.post('/api/contact')
```

Comment: You might be right from that angle, as I kept changing the path thinking it was incorrect. But on a call with @manniL he pointed out it was because I had set up my environment to run on 0.0.0.0, and I should have configured axios to load on the same IP address, hence why it couldn't find the script.